# Drawing at specific coordinates in a loop

Tags: c++, canvas, drawing

I am trying to write a program which simply reads through a multidimensional array (using 'for' loops) and if it encounters a certain letter (like 'A'), it would draw a rectangular shape (im using canvas library and functions to draw the shapes).

I'm trying to actually draw a maze-like map using canvas. But for some odd reason, it is not coming out right. I'm assuming it's a problem with reading the array, which I don't know why.

the multidimensional array read input from a text file which looks like this (a sample):
This is the layout of the maze map I am attempting to create using canvas.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
A.........A.........A
A.........A.........A
A...............AAAAA
AAAAA...............A
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

of course the 'A' will be replaced with a filled rectangle to represent the wall

the '.' represents the path.

here is my code:

```
void MazeGame::DrawMap(Canvas &canvas, char (&map)[20][26]) 
{ 
    double drawx = 200; 
    double drawy = 200;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if(map[i][j] == 'A') 
            {
                canvas.DrawFillRect(drawx+10, drawy, 10, 10);
            } 

            if(map[i][j] == '.')
            {
                map[i][j] = ' ';  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i wrote this function in a class.

I initialized two 'double' variables, drawx and drawy, as 200. That is considered to be the x and y origin coordinate where the shape will be drawn.
Of course as the array of chars is being read, the x & y coordinate has to move accordingly to how the maze layout is displayed in the text file or else, when the shape is drawn, it would simply draw over or overwrite the previously drawn shapes. I don't want that

I feel that this is so simple but the output is really confusing me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not understanding you, I'm afraid. What happens when you run the code? A cursory look at the posted code makes me think that you need to increment drawX and drawY by a multiple of i and j, probably 10 (so drawX + 10*i, drawY + 10*j, or something). I gather that the last arguments to DrawFillRect are the width and height of the rect?

Comment: This function should be called `DrawMapAndReplaceDotsWithSpaces`. Seriously, combining different functionalities (like drawing a map and replacing dots with spaces) into one function is seriously bad programming. If you need both of these capabilites write two functions, one for each.

Comment: what happens is that i only see two rectangles drawn and they were spaced out. that's all that appeared on the screen

Comment: @anjruu and yes the last two arguments are the width and height of the rect.

Answer (score 2):

You're not incrementing *drawx* and *drawy* so the program is always drawing at (210,200).

```
canvas.DrawFillRect(10*i + drawx, j*10 + drawy, 10, 10);
```

---

Also You might want to have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

and move the dot replacement module into another function.

Comment: @user2188311 Do You understand where the problem was?

Comment: @pivovarit +1 for awesome yoyo skills

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
if(map[i][j] == 'A')
{
    canvas.DrawFillRect(i * 10 + drawx, j * 10 + drawy, 10, 10);
}
```

This way you are translating the x and y coordinates of each rectangle.

Think about it this way:

```
where: 
    i = 0, x = 0 * 10 + 200 = 200
    i = 1, x = 1 * 10 + 200 = 210
    i = 2, x = 2 * 10 + 200 = 220
    i = 3, x = 3 * 10 + 200 = 230
    ect...
```

Comment: A multiplication of the base coordinates? I don't think it's what he wants to do here

Comment: ok thats great but it's still not outputting it how it is shown in the text file

Comment: Will you update your question with an example of the output you are seeing?

Comment: Perhaps you need to swap the i & j in the multiplication. Let me know if that works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @jeremynealbrown it seems as though it's only outputting the first 26 elements of the array. it is not looping throughout the whole array.

Comment: basically from map[0][0] to map[0][26]. i dont think it's really going any further in the array or else it would had outputted more rectangles at different places.

Answer (score 0):

You're never drawing anything at any other position than (210, 200).

When drawing, you should be doing something like:

```
canvas.DrawFillRect(drawx + 10 * j, drawy + 10 * i, 10, 10)
```

Assuming the array is represented in the standard [height][width] form.

Comment: i believe it is right? i mean arent multi-dimensional arrays automatically read like that?

Comment: Not automatically, but it does appear that you are doing it that way. So, it should work as expected.